# MySQL: Change compression on an existing InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb, compression

Is there any way to turn on compression for an existing table? I don't care if there's downtime for this.

[The docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html) only mention setting compression when the table is created.

Comment: I'd just try an `ALTER TABLE ... FORCE` once the new settings have been changed.

Comment: What new settings? I'm asking if I have a normal (uncompressed) table, how would I compress it e.g. on console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE xxx ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE xxx ROW_FORMAT=Compressed` apparently works too, mentioned here https://www.lullabot.com/articles/squeeze-save-disk-space-with-mysql-compression. Thanks.

Comment: Ack, was getting confused about if you wanted removing or adding. More coffee required.

Comment: @danblack - `DYNAMIC` is not compressed, but otherwise very similar.

Comment: @mahemoff - Please report on how much smaller the table is (see `SHOW TABLE STATUS`).  The ratios I have seen have been 2:1 compression.

Comment: @RickJames I actually tweeted some benchmarks yesterday :) https://twitter.com/mahemoff/status/1092181875785957377 Uncannily close to 2:1

Comment: @mahemoff - Thanks!  Compression routines handle most forms of "text" at about 3:1, so the 2:1 was depressing when I first heard it.  Is 2:1, etc, worth the effort?

Comment: @mahemoff - 4:1 for the compressed dump -- Note that the _dump_ may be larger or smaller than the db footprint itself.

Comment: @RickJames It's probably because there are a few metadata columns alongisde it and each is indexed (2 timestamps and a ~40 char fingerprint string which won't compress at all). 3:1 might be closer to reality if it's really only strings.

Comment: @RickJames "Is 2:1, etc, worth the effort?". It is for my use case, which is a large corpus of strings that rarely change. Disk size and IO are much bigger constraints than CPU on a typical VPS, ime.

Comment: I prefer to manually 'compress' long strings, then store them into `BLOBs`.  (Of course, this does not work if I need to apply any SQL to the underlying text.)

Comment: Just to weigh in with my own compression stats: 3 fields (int, json, datetime), avg row length 76KB, 1.4M rows. Went from 105GB to 23.6GB.